# Comparing Bool values in Python

Tags: python

If 2 of 3 Values are True then Print true, if not Print false.

```
output = ""
w1 = input() 
w2 = input() 
w3 = input() 

output = w1 and w2 or w1 and w3 or w2 and w3

print(output)
```

I dont understand why this code prints False when w1 and w3 are true.

This is working but i dont understand the deference

```
output = ""
w1 = not input() == "False"
w2 = not input() == "False"
w3 = not input() == "False"

output = w1 and w2 or w1 and w3 or w2 and w3

print(output)
```

Comment: The string `"False"` will not evaluate falsey, the only string that evaluates falsey is the empty string `''`.

Comment: `input` returns a string. A string is only *falsey* when it's empty. Any other string is *truthy*. `"False"` is *truthy*.

Comment: `from collections import Counter` `output = Counter([w1, w2, w3])['True'] >= 2`…

Comment: Also, you should do `input() != 'False'` instead of negating a positive comparison…

Comment: `[w1, w2, w3].count(True) == 2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one.** In this case, w1,w2,w3 will be `Boolean`.

```
w1= input() =='True'
w2= input() =='True'
w3= input() =='True'

output = ((w1 and w2) or (w1 and w3) or (w2 and w3)) and (not (w1 and w2 and w3))

print(output)
```

Comment: what if all 3 of the values are true?

Comment: yeah, and op said, that they want `True` if 2 of them are `True`, otherwise `False`

Comment: Thank you @Mahrkeenerh. Sorry, I didn't notice this part. I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to have `True` output, when exactly 2 of the 3 variables are `"True"` (so all 3 variables being `"True"` will result in `False`), use:

```
w1 = 1 if input() == "True" else 0
w2 = 1 if input() == "True" else 0
w3 = 1 if input() == "True" else 0

output = True if w1 + w2 + w3 == 2 else False
```